# Overcome System.QueryException with EntityDefinition not supporting queryMore

Tags: soql, dynamic-apex

I received the following error in my 2GMP developed

```
System.QueryException: EntityDefinition does not support queryMore(), use LIMIT to restrict the results to a single batch
```

This is very strange error, since it doesn't occur on other environment but it occurs only on one environment with very specific case

```
List<String> apiNames = new List<String>();
for (EntityDefinition def: [SELECT QualifiedApiName FROM EntityDefinition WHERE IsCustomizable = True AND IsApexTriggerable = True ]) {
    apiNames.add(def.QualifiedApiName);
}
```

This error happens if there are a lot of objects (more than 200) and the filtered objects do not belong to the first chunk of object.

[The documentation for EntityDefinition object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm) doesn't mention about any SOQL query limitations.

If I use `LIMIT 200` this error doesn't reproduce

```
List<String> apiNames = new List<String>();
for (EntityDefinition def: [SELECT QualifiedApiName FROM EntityDefinition WHERE IsCustomizable = True AND IsApexTriggerable = True LIMIT 200]) {
    apiNames.add(def.QualifiedApiName);
}
```

but then I will not be able to get all the records I need. Is there a way to overcome this silly error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the entity doesn't support queryMore, you need to do so manually. Something like this:

```
String[] apiNames = new String[0];
String lastEntityQueried;
do {
    EntityDefinition[] defs = [
        SELECT QualifiedApiName 
        FROM EntityDefinition 
        WHERE QualifiedApiName > :lastEntityQueried AND 
            IsCustomizable = TRUE AND 
            IsApexTriggerable = TRUE 
        ORDER BY QualifiedApiName ASC 
        LIMIT 2000];
    if(defs.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }
    for(EntityDefinition def: defs) {
        apiNames.add(def.QualifiedApiName);
    }
    lastEntityQueried = apiNames[apiNames.size()-1];
    if(defs.size() < 2000) {
        break;
    }
} while(true);
```

This gives you a "manual offset" design so you can get all the values. Since there's a hard limit of about 3,000 custom objects, this shouldn't need more than 2 queries to complete.

Comment: static code analyzers will complain on the SOQL inside a loop. I think I might use some inline code for this instead

Comment: @Patlatus Static analysis is only a hint system. There are times when the rules must be broken. If you're worried about security review, just explain the purpose, they should allow it.

Comment: I agree, still I think I would prefer to have literally two SOQL queries so that maintainers, who will maintain the code, will easily understand that only two SOQL queries will be performed in this case at most

Comment: @Patlatus Such hard-coding isn't a good idea. It used to be that you could have 9,999 custom objects. Such limits may change in the future. A loop is the most appropriate solution.

Comment: If we had 9999 custom objects, that would use 5 SOQL queries instead of 2. If we had another 98 SOQL queries in the transaction, that would hit the SOQL Statements limit. If we use loop, we will not know that this code use more than 2 expected SOQL queries. Also, this code can be enhanced to avoid additional SOQL query if the previous result size is less than 2000.

Comment: @Patlatus Yes, I thought about that afterwards. Definitely break if the result was <2k.

Comment: @Patlatus Also, if you're already at 98 queries, it's long past time you started optimizing. Until/unless they give us queryMore support, this is the solution I'd use in my projects.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with [SOQL For Loop](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm).

> **SOQL For Loops Versus Standard SOQL Queries**
>
> SOQL for loops differ from standard SOQL statements because of the
> method they use to retrieve sObjects. While the standard queries
> discussed in SOQL and SOSL Queries can retrieve either the count of a
> query or a number of object records, SOQL for loops retrieve all
> sObjects, using efficient chunking with calls to the query and
> queryMore methods of the SOAP API. Developers should always use a SOQL
> for loop to process query results that return many records, to avoid
> the limit on heap size.

It is possible to use the following code snippet

```
List<String> apiNames = new List<String>();
List<EntityDefinition> defs = [SELECT QualifiedApiName FROM EntityDefinition WHERE IsCustomizable = True AND IsApexTriggerable = True];
for (EntityDefinition def: defs) {
    apiNames.add(def.QualifiedApiName);
}
```

to get the desired result and avoid the specified `QueryException`.

To overcome the problem with 2000 records limit,

```
String[] apiNames = new String[0];
EntityDefinition[] defs = [
    SELECT QualifiedApiName 
    FROM EntityDefinition 
    WHERE IsCustomizable = TRUE AND IsApexTriggerable = TRUE 
    ORDER BY QualifiedApiName ASC 
    LIMIT 2000
];
for(EntityDefinition def: defs) {
    apiNames.add(def.QualifiedApiName);
}
lastEntityQueried = apiNames[apiNames.size()-1];
if (defs.size() == 2000) {
    defs = [
        SELECT QualifiedApiName 
        FROM EntityDefinition 
        WHERE QualifiedApiName > :lastEntityQueried AND IsCustomizable = TRUE AND IsApexTriggerable = TRUE 
        ORDER BY QualifiedApiName ASC 
        LIMIT 2000
    ];
    for(EntityDefinition def: defs) {
        apiNames.add(def.QualifiedApiName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you'll still be limited to 2000 rows in that scenario, but it's better than 200.

Comment: @sfdcfox do you know any way to replicate this scenario? How can I achieve 2000+ objects in an org if I don't have unlimited or performance edition org and I don't have any package including lots of objects?

Comment: Created a separate question for that https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343102/is-this-possible-to-replicate-a-case-with-2000-objects-in-an-org-to-reproduce-a

Comment: The solution is to use more than one query. I'll add an answer here.