# Is this possible to replicate a case with 2000+ objects in an org to reproduce an issue which happens only in this case?

Tags: replication, unlimited

Certain SF functionality depends on the number of objects which exist in the target subscriber organization, for example, querying EntityDefinition may or may not fail depending if there are 2001+ objects in the org or not (also order of objects matter).

To reproduce such a scenario, we need some Development organization where we can have 2001+ objects. If I had Unlimited or performance edition, I could create 2000 objects manually and install one certified managed package from AppExchange with one object to replicate this situation. Alternatively, if I had a package which passed AppExchange security review with 1000 or 2000 objects, I could install such a package on the Developer Edition or Enterprise Trial Edition org and have 2001+ objects total in such an org.

I can't even get an Unlimited Trial org since when I go to Salesforce / Edition and sign up for Unlimited trial, it creates an Professional Edition.

Also Partner Environment hub doesn't allow to create unlimited edition trial org.

How can I replicate this scenario? How can I achieve 2000+ objects in an org if I don't have unlimited or performance edition org and I don't have any package passed AppExchange security review including lots of objects?